# Struts2 Populate Lists

Tags: java, list, collections, struts2, ognl

I am having issues populating a List of User defined object attributes in Struts2.

Here is my example (getters / setters ommitted):

> public class Foo {     private String attr1;     private String attr2; 
>   }
>
> public class Bar {     private List foos;  }
>
> public class StrutsAction extends ActionSupport  {    private Bar bar;  }

I have code in JSP as follows (extract):

```
<tr><td><input type="text" name="bar.foos.attr1"/></td><td><input type="text" name="bar.foos.attr2"</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="bar.foos.attr1"/></td><td><input type="text" name="bar.foos.attr2"</td></tr>
```

I need each table row to create 1 foo item in the List with each attribute, however my code creats a new foo object for each attribute when passed through and I end up with 4 foos rather than 2!

I understand I can solve the problem with hard coding the Index into the html as follows:

```
<tr><td><input type="text" name="bar.foos[0].attr1"/></td><td><input type="text" name="bar.foos[0].attr2"</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="text" name="bar.foos[1].attr1"/></td><td><input type="text" name="bar.foos[1].attr2"</td></tr>
```

I was wondering if it can be done without hard coding the Indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use the Struts 2 iterator tag:

```
<s:iterator var="foo" value="bar.foos">
   <tr><td><s:property value="attr1"/> .....
</s:iterator>
```

If it does not work, we can think in other solution.

You can find more information here: http://struts.apache.org/2.3.1/docs/iterator.html

[]s

Comment: This displays only whereas OP is creating a form.

Comment: Hi.  This is for getting property.  I need to set values from a variable length table

Comment: The list of Foo is already populated when you make the form? is it empty?

Comment: It is empty.  Javascrip will create the rows

Answer (score 1):

You said you have variable number of rows. Let's name it `numOfRows`... Try to rewrite your example like so:

```
<table>
<s:iterator status="stat" value="(numOfRows).{ #this }" >
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="bar.foos[%{#stat.index}].attr1"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="bar.foos[%{#stat.index}].attr2"/></td>
    </tr>
</s:iterator>
</table>
```

You can find docs about Iterator tag [there](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.12/docs/iterator.html)... Look at the bottom of the page.

---

If you don't have `numOfRows` at render phase, then I am afraid the only way to generate textfields is javascript on client side....

### [EDIT]

Regarding indexes... You don't have to bother if you have indexes something like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="bar.foos[0].attr1"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="bar.foos[0].attr2"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="bar.foos[3].attr1"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="bar.foos[3].attr2"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="bar.foos[5].attr1"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="bar.foos[5].attr2"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Struts will do the conversion just right... You just have to be aware, that objects who's indexes are missing will be null... So you should filter them out in the action.

Comment: Yes the number of rows are variable. Problem I have is that I need to build the html on the fly using JQuery and therefore cannot use struts tags as I am passed the rendering phase.  Furthermore I am using ModelDriven<Bar> so not sure if this complicates it further

Comment: On reading the Iterator tag docs this seems to be talking about Iterating over existing Values.  I dont have existing values.  I have an variable row number table with numous attributes

Comment: You can use Iterator tag without existing Values... You can simulate a simple loop to... I will correct the answer....

Comment: I really appreciate your answer.  This works, however the difficulty I have is that I need to add and remove elements from the table which adds and removes indexes.  For example, I might add 5 table rows, then delete row 3 then add another which will cause problems with rejigging the indexes.  This solution still uses Indexes once html generates which will cause me problems.